# involving the Return key in a System Preferences keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, automator, shortcut

I'm trying to get used to a macOS development environment after years of being an i3 junkie and I want to be able to use keyboard shortcuts to launch applications. I learned that you can do this by writing simple Automator services and then making keyboard shortcuts to those services (under System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services). I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35954589/6558085) and I now have the Automator service I need in place and I can also tell it to use a shortcut like <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open it.

However, I don't want to use <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal. I would like to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> instead. When I try to do that, System Preferences acts as though I haven't specified any shortcut at all; I think it doesn't like to set up shortcuts involving the <kbd>return</kbd> key. It lets you use most other keys though, as far as I can tell. (aside: I played around and it looks like the only keys you aren't allowed to use in this menu are <kbd>return</kbd>, <kbd>delete</kbd>, <kbd>caps lock</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>.)

Does anyone know a way to work around that?

- An ideal workaround would let me set it up directly in the System Preferences Menu. (that feels impossible to me so far but I have no idea why)
- Second place would be doing it using config files somewhere on the filesystem. (akin something like an `~/.xbindkeys` file under X11).
- Least desirable to me are solutions involving installing third-party
  keyboard automation tools. (I think I can figure out how to do that on
  my own, I'd just like to avoid it.)

I'm using macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know a way to work around that?
>
> - Second place would be doing it using config files somewhere on the filesystem.

In **macOS Catalina**, it's the **~Library/Preferences/pbs.plist** *file* that stores information about the *services* listed at: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

This answer is mainly focused on applying the **⌘↩** (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>) *keyboard shortcut* to a *service* listed at **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** and without concern to the issues with creating an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* and assigning it a *global keyboard shortcut* in reference to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**.

Having created an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* and assigned it a temporary *global keyboard shortcut* of **⌘]** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, I then did the following to change it to: **⌘↩**

<sup>**Note:** The name of the target **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* is: **New Terminal Window**</sup>

Closed: **System Preferences**

Opened: **Terminal**

```
% defaults read pbs | grep 'New Terminal Window'
        "(null) - New Terminal Window - runWorkflowAsService" =         {
%
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :NSServicesStatus:'(null) - New Terminal Window - runWorkflowAsService':key_equivalent @↩" ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist
%
```

Then went to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** and verified the target **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* had the **⌘↩** *keyboard shortcut*.

I then pressed the **⌘↩** *keyboard shortcut*, responded to the **Security & Privacy** dialog box, and now have a new **Terminal** *window*.

---

**Notes:**

If after running the `PlistBudy` *command* and then checking **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** to see that **⌘↩** was assigned to the target **service's** *keyboard shortcut* and testing... If the **⌘↩** *keyboard shortcut* doesn't work, try the following before rebooting:

- Try the the **service** from the **Services** menu, then try agin with the **⌘↩** *keyboard shortcut*.
- If that does't work, execute the `PlistBudy` *command* again while appending `; killall cfprefsd` to the *command*. Then repeat the step above.
- If nether of these steps work, execute the `PlistBudy` *command* again and immediately reboot.

This was done from an **Admin** account.

This was done under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The **AppleScript** *code* used in a **Run AppleScript** *action* of the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* was coded to work whether or not **Terminal** was already running.

---

[image]

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thank you! I was in the same situation as you (admin account, US-localized English). Note for anyone else, I did have to reboot before the use of PlistBuddy took effect and replaced my shortcut.

Comment: @sinback, I've added an additional note staringt at the top of the **Notes:** _section_... If after running the `PlistBudy` _command_...` and while it not applicable to you now that you've rebooted, hopefully it will benefit others, or you the next time you need to employ the method presented herein. Thanks.